# Why would my navigation go away when I take out an image?

Tags: html, css

I have a grey image on the left side of this website.  When I remove this image from the website, the navigation disappears?  I've added a couple pictures to showing what's happening.

Before[image]

After[image]

```
HTML
<body>

        <div id="header">

            <div id="pics">
                <img id="remax" src="newImages/remaxlogo.jpg">
                <img id="jaytext" src="newImages/jaycousins.png">

                <img  id="papa" src="newImages/papaPic.jpg">

                <img id ="darkTextBackground" src="newImages/darktextbackgroubd.jpg">

                <img id ="commercialtext" src="newImages/commercialtext.png">


                <img id ="leftsidebackground" src="newImages/leftsidebackground.jpg"> **THIS ONE WOULD BE TAKEN OUT

           </div>   

            <ul>
                <li class="selected">
                    <a href="/">home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/opportunities">Opportunities</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/projmanagment">Project Management</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/aboutjay">About Jay</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/community">Community</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#papa {
    display: block;     
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 500px;
    margin-left:0px;           
    height:270px;    
}
#jaytext{
    width:470px;
    height:75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top:7.2%;
    left:38.4%;

}
#darkTextBackground{
    margin: 0 auto;    
    width:550px;
    height:73px;
    position:absolute;
    top:19.9%;
    left:38.8%; 

}
#commercialtext{
    margin: 0 auto;   
    height:53px;
    width:505px;
    position:absolute;
    top:19.4%;
    left:38.59%;

}
#leftsidebackground{
    display: block;     
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    left:-40%;
}
#text{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;

}
/*position:relative makes the images static and they wont move if the window moves*/
#pics{
    position:relative;
}


#header ul {
    background: url(../images/menu-border.gif) no-repeat bottom left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0px 1px;
    width: 970px;

    /*changes navigation position*/
    position:relative;
    top:-172.5%;
    left:9.3%;


}

#header ul li {
    background: url(../images/bg-menu.gif) repeat-x bottom center;
    border-top: 2px solid #4f5342;
    float: left;

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;


}
```

It doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: pls share your fiddle code

Comment: @anji Please, don't use jsfiddle, please just use the SO integrated function.

Comment: You forgot to give us the end of the `<body>`...

Comment: This is a template website that I am modifying.  To give you the entire html/css you guys would be reading for days.   I only gave what I thought was necessary